# Como passar um componente no Vue para variável?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<template>
<div>
    <h2><Info/></h2>
    <input type="text" maxlength="1" value=`<Info/>`/>
    <input type="text" maxlength="1" />
    <input type="text" maxlength="1" />
    <input type="text" maxlength="1" />
    <input type="text" maxlength="1" />
    <input type="text" maxlength="1" />
 </div>
</template>
<script>


import Info from "./Info.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {Info}
}
</script>
```

Gostaria que o valor de  fosse passado para uma variável, ou até mesmo para o value do input alí direto. Porém não sei como fazer isso, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Qual você espera que seja a representação textual de um componente Vue?

Comment: É apenas o valor de um atributo, que está sendo enviado numa <div>{{valor}}</div>. No template a única coisa que ele me retorna é esse valor, por isso eu gostaria de colocar ele dentro do value do input.

Comment: @Tester chegou a tentar a solucao que propus?

Answer (score -1):

Voce precisa adicionar um novo componente que recebe o componente `Info` como `prop` e usar o `v-model` em combinacao com o `data` no seu export default.

App.vue

```
<template>
<div>
    <h2><Info/></h2>
    <CustomInput valor=Info />
    <input type="text" maxlength="1" />
    <input type="text" maxlength="1" />
    <input type="text" maxlength="1" />
    <input type="text" maxlength="1" />
    <input type="text" maxlength="1" />
 </div>
</template>
<script>


import Info from "./Info.vue";
import CustomInput from "./CustomInput.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {Info, CustomInput},

}
</script>
```

CustomInput.vue

```
<script>
  export default {
  props: ['valor'],
  data(props) {
        return {
            localValue: props.valor
        }
    }

}
</script>

<template>
  <input type="text" maxlength="1" v-model="localValue"/>
</template>
```

Comment: Razão do downvote? A solução funciona

Answer (score -4):

Tenta fazer o bind do valor que você precisa +- dessa forma:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="1" :value="<Info/>" />
```

Não tenho certeza se irá funcionar, pois estou longe de meu notebook.

Comment: Deste modo não funciona

Answer (score -4):

usa o v-model para o input e faz o envio do dados por props